# WHMCS provisioning module, add custom field by default

Tags: php, whmcs

I'm making a provisioning module for WHMCS which can monitor domains, it's not depend on server or anything else.

It should works like this:

User orders a plan of this service and enters some data like domain name or choosing something from a custom dropdown, then in `_CreateAccount` function, I have to send an api to the monitoring server which is not a WHM/Cpanel server of course.
**I need these custom fields to be in order page by default, Is there any way?**